# How to scrape google videos page thumbnails?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am currently working on a scraping project in which I am scraping Google videos page, but I got stuck at a problem when I got to know that it requires to use ytimg to scrape Youtube directed video thumbnails.

I am using cheerio for parsing, here is my code:

```
        $('.G6SP0b').each((i,el) => {
        img[i] = $(el)
        .find('.h1hFNe').attr('src');//which is the base64 image
        })
```

So in the code I am extracting every thumbnails from google videos page, which are in gif/base64 format, but I want to store each Youtube directed video thumbnail into the image array with their respective URL in jpg format.

Please correct my code, or suggest me any other way of converting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just used this method, I scraped the URL of that Youtube video and used this URL for getting thumbnail:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/videoID/mqdefault.jpg
```

And here is my code:

```
        $('.G6SP0b').each((i,el) => {
        image[i] = $(el)
        .find('.h1hFNe').attr('src')
    })
    $('.egMi0').each((i,el) => {
        link[i] = $(el)
        .find('a').attr('href')
        link[i] = link[i].replace("%3F" , "?")
        link[i] = link[i].replace("%3D" , "=")
        link[i] = link[i].substring(7,link[i].indexOf("&"))
        if(link[i].includes("www.youtube.com"))
        {
            image[i] = `http://img.youtube.com/vi/${link[i].substring(32)}/mqdefault.jpg`
        }
    })
```

And that is how I am getting my results:

```
"videoResults": [
{
  "thumbnail": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/ET0G1FYxWqc/mqdefault.jpg",
  "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET0G1FYxWqc"
},
{
  "thumbnail": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/-QXrYIHODzE%26vl%3Den-US/mqdefault.jpg",
  "link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QXrYIHODzE%26vl%3Den-US"
},
{
  "thumbnail": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",
  "link": "https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/33822691/nfl-draft-2022-national-title-super-bowl-winning-qb-record-draft-night-part-impressive-year-georgia-bulldogs"
},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cheerio` for scraping images from Google Search you can't get it directly from the `img` tag, because the `src` attribute by default contains only a 1x1 placeholder, and the full resolution image is loaded by javascript. To find a full resolution image, you need to extract it from base64 encoding in `script` tags. Check the code below and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Google-Video-Tab-scrape-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js)

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");

const searchQuery = "minecraft";                             // what we want to search
const encodedQuery = encodeURI(searchQuery);            // what we want to search for in URI encoding

const BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";

const AXIOS_OPTIONS = {
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
  },                                              // adding the User-Agent header as one way to prevent the request from being blocked
  params: {
    q: encodedQuery,                                // our encoded search string
    tbm: "vid",                                     // parameter defines the type of search you want to do ("vid" means videos)
    hl: "en",                                       // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
    gl: "us",                                       // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  },
};

function getVideosInfo() {
  return axios(BASE_URL, AXIOS_OPTIONS).then(({ data }) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    const patternForBase64 = /s='(?<img>[^']+)';\w+\s\w+=\['(?<id>\w+_\d+)'];/gm;       //https://regex101.com/r/pMd0yx/1
    const patternForLinks = /"(?<id>[^":]+)":"(?<link>[^"]+)"/gm;                       //https://regex101.com/r/p5nj8R/1

    const imagesWithBase64 = [...data.matchAll(patternForBase64)].map(({ groups }) => ({ id: groups.id, img: groups.img.replaceAll("\\x3d", "") }));
    const imagesWithLinks = [...data.matchAll(patternForLinks)].map(({ groups }) => ({ id: groups.id, link: groups.link }));

    return [...$(".dFd2Tb .dXiKIc")].map((el) => {
      return {
        link: $(el).find("a").attr("href"),
        image:
          imagesWithBase64.find(({ id }) => id === $(el).find("img").attr("id"))?.img || imagesWithLinks.find(({ id }) => id === $(el).find("img").attr("id"))?.link,
      };
    });
  });
}

getVideosInfo().then(console.log);
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmB9b5njVbA",
      "image":"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
   },
   ...and other results
]
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Google Video Results API](https://serpapi.com/videos-results) from SerpApi. SerpApi is a free API with 100 searches per month. If you need more searches, there are paid plans.

The difference is that all that needs to be done is just to iterate over a ready-made, structured JSON instead of coding everything from scratch maintaining, figuring out how to bypass blocks from Google, and selecting correct selectors which could be time-consuming at times. [Check out the playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=minecraft&location=Austin%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&gl=us&hl=en&tbm=vid).

Usage:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY); //your api key from serpapi.com

const searchString = "minecraft";                        // what we want to search

const params = {
  engine: "google",                                     // search engine
  q: searchString,                                      // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",                          // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                                             // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                             // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
  tbm: "vid"                                            // parameter defines the type of search you want to do ("nws" means news)
};

const getVideosData = function ({ video_results }) {
  return video_results.map((result) => {
    const { link, thumbnail = "No image" } = result;
    return {
      link,
      thumbnail,
    }
  })
};

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  })
}

getJson(params).then(getVideosData).then(console.log)
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmB9b5njVbA",
      "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6294dec729d17745dfdc3c84/images/23c7d943b97e967d87bd9ee7e4d0109cb6c0b7356adf2a71edf2f29dcbd11563.jpeg"
   },
   {
      "link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-fMtNOS_gU",
      "thumbnail":"https://serpapi.com/searches/6294dec729d17745dfdc3c84/images/23c7d943b97e967d4166ae8a934a93a29023f829db54715a9b4305dd4c904e2d.jpeg"
   },
   ...and other results
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: How can I convert data:base64 images to jpg or png in node js? It will be of very very great help if you response.

Comment: try to check [this blog post](https://dev.to/dnature/convert-a-base64-data-into-an-image-in-node-js-3f88)